# Column default value not changes after moving a document

Tags: document-library, default-value

I have two folders with a default value setting.

**For example:**

On folder one the default value is 0815 and
on folder two the default value is 999.
When a document is stored in folder one and will be moved to folder two, the column default value is not changing.

Is there anything i can do that the default value will change when a document is moved from one folder to another?

Comment: When you move the document I believe it moves the meta data along. Not sure whether you can tackle this out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Michael says above, a default value only occurs at default, it doesn't change values if one exists.

Can you use a SPD workflow to change the value? How are you moving the document?

I would imagine that at the worst, you could setup a workflow to run on update and if the value of the field you are looking at is 0815, change it to 999. No update would occur on items that are already 999.

Comment: Hi DLoweinc! Thanks for your answer. The documents will be moved via drag and drop or in the open with explorer function. We don't use SPD so i have to find another solution for this topic.

Comment: A workflow that is set to run on change would still work for you in this scenario. Unless I am missing some other requirement